# Insert image in webpage

Tags: php, image

With a SELECT I read records from my sql database.
The name of the associated photo file is also stored in the user record. The photo itself is in wp-content/uploads/photo.
I am unable to display the record including photo in my html page with the php script below.
What is wrong is this part of my php-script?

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo    "<table class=a><tr>" . 
    "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>" . 
    "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>" . 
    "<td>" . "<img src='\wp-content\uploads\photos . ($row['photo'])'"> . "</td>" .     
    "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: URLs are supposed to have forward slashes not backslashes, for a start. What error are you getting when it tries to load the image? Have you looked in the browser's Console / network tools to find out?

Comment: Is it `photo` (as you said in the question) or `photos` (as you have it in your code?). Also, unless the image name is stored with a leading `/` in the database (`/foo.jpg`), you need to add `/` before outputting the image name, or it will be `/photosfoo.jpg`.

Comment: I replaced the backslashes.
The error-code is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in (my script)

Comment: Your concatenation and quoting is wrong. You either use concatenation `"string" . $var . "string"` or variable interpolation (works inside double quotes) `"string $var string"`. [Read more in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). Right now, you're mixing it incorrectly.  The error comes from that the closing `>` is outside the strings closing quote: `photos . ($row['photo'])'">` should be `photos/" . $row['photo'] . "'>"`

Comment: I replaced the img-row as follows:   
"<td>" ."<img src='/wp-content/uploads/photos/" . $row['photo'] . "'>"  . "</td>" .
Now no error, but no display?

Comment: Do you get the default "missing image" icon instead?